# How can I do an in-place update of a file with perltidy?

Tags: perl, lint, perl-tidy

If I want to an in-place update of a file with perltidy, how can I do it? Let's say I want to run perl-tidy on `foo.pl` but I want to the changes to be in `foo.pl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the options `-b` and `-bext='/'`

```
perltidy -b -bext='/' foo.pl
```

[Taken from the man page](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/perltidy.html)

**Make sure you don't have `-st` provided or the `-b` and `-bext` options do nothing; this was actually my problem.**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `perltidy` has a [native solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222870/589924). Not all programs do. The `sponge` utility can be used to achieve in-place editing for programs that don't natively support it.

```sh
prog file | sponge file
```

Comment: @JRFerguson, Kinda. It links to the other answer. I wanted to acknowledge that this might not be the best answer in this specific case, but it might help others.